# Admob 4.1 for Android: Changing background color

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

Im trying to change the background color of the ad to make it fit better into my app. I found that this could be configured through their web page, but for some reason this does not work 100% of the time, sometimes the ads appear with their normal looks.

So I choose "Use colors set in client code" and tried to change the ad-look in my app, but I have been perfectly unable to do this. I found many good guides for pre-4.1.0, but none for this version. Any help is really appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: I have never used admob, but it sounds like that ad designers used an image for their ad that the background color cannot be changed (or seen because the image uses all the alotted space with no transparency alpha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work when admob filled their adspace with ads from google ads. Turning off this filler made the ads always look the way I wanted, but then the fill rate was disasterous.